# When clicking on text will link me to table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Currently I have a textbox that will display some text based on the search criteria. The text that is displayed will be the name of a table. Is it possible for me to make it so that if I click on the name of the table in the textbox, it will open the table for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the click event of the textbox:

```
DoCmd.OpenTable Me.MyTextbox
```

Edit re comment, this is a sketch and will not work if the table name has spaces.

```
Private Sub Text0_Click()
    i = Me.Text0.SelStart
    j = InStr(i, Me.Text0, " ")
    k = InStrRev(Me.Text0, " ", i)
    tbl = Mid(Me.Text0, k, j - k)
    DoCmd.OpenTable tbl
End Sub
```

Or better, capture the construction in a listbox by row, rather than in a textbox.

Based on you code sample, you can say:

```
Public Sub SearchTables(SearchString As String)
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim sTable As String
Dim sField As String
Dim sMsg As String
sMsg = ""
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs

    sTable = tdf.Name
    sField = SearchTable(sTable, SearchString)
    If sField <> vbNullString Then
        sMsg = sMsg & ";" & sTable & ";" & sField
    End If
Next
'listbox0
'Row source type: Value List
'Column count: 2
'You will get a two column listbox with table in one column
'and field in another
Forms!Search!listbox0.RowSource = Mid(sMsg, 2)
End Sub
```

Then in the click event for listbox0:

```
Private Sub listbox0_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenTable Me.listbox0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, in the box, the format is this:
Table = NAMEOFTABLE Field = NAMEOFSEARCH
I need it to allow me to click on NAMEOFTABLE and it will link me to the table? Is that possible? There might be more than 1 search results so it will become something like this:
Table = NAMEOFTABLE Field = NAMEOFSEARCH
Table = NAMEOFTABLE2 Field = NAMEOFSEARCH2

Comment: Hi,
Below is my code. It is a search form, which will search in all of the tables for the string, then list the tables where it appears under.
The code is in the pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/ww16MeE9
Thanks a lot

Comment: I am really sorry for this, but how would I make that list box? I don't have much prior experience with VBA so if you can guide me through this it will be great.

Comment: Do you know how to create a textbox?

Comment: Yes, I know how to make the listbox. However, how would I populate the list box with the values from the text box? That's what I am having a bit of trouble with.

Comment: I am trying to put in the items according to the values of sTable and sField: Here are my code:
`Form_Search.listbox0.AddItem.List(count, 0) = (sTable)
        Form_Search.listbox0.AddItem.List(count, 1) = (sField)
        count = count + 1`
It is returning an argument not optional error. Do you know what it is? Before this I have defined count as an Integer and count = 0 at the beginning.

Comment: Just an update. I have managed to get everything working. Thank you very much for your help in this. I am just wondering, is it possible for it to make it so that when I click on the name, it will take me directly to the place where the search string is found? So it will open the table as listed above, then go to the field that it is in?

Comment: I provided the code for populating the listbox. It is shown above. There should have been very little for you to do, other than add a listbox with the proper settings.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to go to the relevant field other than by using a query. Either "SELECT " & Me.listBox0.Column(1) & ",* FROM " & Me.ListBox0 -- or just select the column by itself. You could also use the search term in a WHERE statement.

Comment: Oh ok that is just an optional thing I want to do. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean specifically clicking on the text that is the name...
so if the text were "John 12345 THE TABLE" you want just THE TABLE to open?

Not enough information to give a solid answer, but if you wanted to just get THE TABLE from the above text then you could use screen coordinates based on where you click in relation to the position of text. It would be far easier to do it another way...

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted. THe TABLE will open if I click on it. That is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If the format of your text is like this:

```
Table = NAMEOFTABLE Field = NAMEOFSEARCH Table = NAMEOFTABLE2 Field = NAMEOFSEARCH2
```

You could use this code:

```
Private Sub Text0_Click()
  i = Me.Text0.SelStart
  If i > 0 Then
    startTable = InStrRev(Me.Text0, "Table = ", i)
    startField = InStr(startTable + 8, Me.Text0, "Field = ")
    If startTable > 0 And i < InStr(startTable + 8, Me.Text0, "Field = ") Then
      DoCmd.OpenTable Mid(Me.Text0, startTable + 8, startField - startTable - 9)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

If you click on the name of any table, it will open that table.

Here a little explanation: using current position of the cursor, I'm searching backwards for the `"Table = "` string, and from there I'm searching for the next string `"Field = "`. All we have to do is to check if the cursor is before next field.